# Pass decimal values php to javascript using json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a php twoD array which is generated from mssql database. I need to pass this array data to javascript. This is the array example:

```
....
    [70] => Array
        (
            [travelled] => 151.63313641031
            [Time] => 2016-08-04 00:00:00
            [Date] => 03-08-2016
            [Cost] => 13.646982276928
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [travelled] => 17.437913283984
            [Time] => 2016-08-05 00:00:00
            [Date] => 04-08-2016
            [Cost] => 1.5694121955586
        )
...
```

I used,

```
json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

The problem is,
In javascript I received numeric value without digits values for cost. Ex: 13, 1

My question is how to pass decimal values php to javascript using json_encode.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `parseInt()` anywhere in your JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue OMG YES, How stupid I am :( Thanks a lot. I spent lot of time to find a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/SXKAr **Edit:** Ah, you found the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thank you for the support. It's my bad I used parseInt in client side which I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not using `parseInt()` on the Client Side.